# "I am going to lecture room" and "I am going for lecture room"?

Tags: difference

What is the difference between: "I am going **to** lecture room" and "I am going **for** lecture room"?

Which one is preferable?

Comment: your two sentences are identical ( and incorrect).  Please [edit]

Comment: Note that singular countable nouns require a determiner. "Room" is a singular countable noun. You need to add a determiner. Next. "to" is chiefly a preposition of motion, whereas "for" is not a preposition of motion. "For" is mainly a preposition of purpose and benefit. In answer to your question, "The correct one is preferable,"

Answer (score 1):

Both are incorrect as native speakers would typically require an article or other determiner before "lecture room".  e.g.

> I am going to *the* lecture room.
>   I am going to *my* lecture room.

As for *to* versus *for*, the preferred choice would be *to*.  Generally we go *to* places, we only go *for* activities or purposes.

So with 'lecture room', which is a place, we have 'to':

> I am going to the lecture room

but with 'lecture', which is an activity, we could say 'for':

> I am going for my lecture.

Although we could also still say

> I am going to my lecture.